# Using {{ var }} to run HTML code in Python Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I have the following Python code

```
...
return render_template('main.html', in_html = in_html)
```

in_html is html code that I want to run in a div once main.html loads

My main.html file

```
...
<div> {{in_html}} </div>
```

This doesn't work, it displays the actual html code as text of the div. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write `{{ in_html|safe }}` to indicate that `in_html` is safe to render as HTML.

Alternatively, use `MarkUp` when passing the value to the template from Python:

```py
from flask import Markup

def foo():
    # ...
    return render_template('main.html', in_html = MarkUp(in_html))
```